# Save everything of an activity

Tags: android, lifecycle, application-restart

I've got an activity and I want to keep everything inside it (Bitmaps, texts, buttons..) so when the user restarts the phone and clicks on my app, everything is like the last time he used it.

Any idea?

I've been reading about the lifecycle of an application in Android, and i know the basics *theoretically* but I don't know how to implement it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need to do anything on objects such as `Buttons` and `TextViews`, since they do not change during your `Activity`'s lifetime. When your application restarts, they just get recreated and they look the same anytime. Things that you want to save are possibly user inputs or downloaded files. If you have any of these, then I'd recommend learning [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) post, it describes different data storage mechanisms in Android. For different kinds of data you'll need different solutions, for example text inputs can be saved in `SharedPreferences`, but bitmaps should probably be saved in the file system. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you too. I'll have a look ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not the best solution, but you can try [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and save different user data into different variables upon exiting.

When the app is restarted, read the values stored in the SharedPreferences and display these values in your respective views.

Other than SharedPreferences, you can also try out [these various options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) according to the type of data you would want to persist!

Comment: I didn't do it! Voting down requires 125 reputation. I'm only 28.

Comment: Ah, okay. Missed that. I am just surprised how the guy below me got an upvote for saying practically the same I did and I was voted down.  Anyway, all the best to you. Good luck! :)

Comment: I can only give one up to you...sorry

Comment: Hey man! That is alright! No apologies needed ! And thanks a tonne for the up! :D